# Increase Jupyter Notebook speed

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook, ram

I'm currently engaged in predictive modeling and machine learning within my Jupyter notebook. It appears that my computations are consuming excessive time, surpassing the 4-hour mark. This issue does not stem from an infinite loop; rather, I'm seeking guidance on how to augment the memory allocation for my existing workbook.

Processeur  12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1255U   1.70 GHz
RAM 16,0 Go (15,7 Go usable)
exploitation system 64 bits, processeur x64

Comment: What makes you think that the RAM is the issue/that the notebook is not already using as much RAM as is available?

Comment: I'm not sure and i don't know how to check

Comment: Okay, then why are you seeking guidance on how to augment memory? Or, let me put it differently: there is no reason to assume this. More likely, your code is slow because, well, it’s inherently slow. To make it run faster you’d have to use less data, or get faster hardware, or potentially rewrite the code to be less inefficient (but in the absence of any evidence I’m assuming that you are using existing ML libraries, so there’s little opportunity for optimisation).

Comment: It might be your model / data that makes it slow. Perhaps try using a simpler model. You can also use a code profiler to see where your code uses a bunch of memory or time, like Scalene.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a free account and use the free usage of services such as Sagemaker or Ml studio and see if it resolves your problem